# Query MySQL Database From Canvas Element?

Tags: java, mysql, servlets, applet, communication

Ok So I'd like trying to figure out the best way to go about making a simple 2D game that runs in the browser. I've looked at HTML5 and the Canvas element. It seems you use JavaScript though and I've read you can't connect to a MySQL database from JavaScript so connection from a Canvas element, which seems to use JavaScript, seems to be out of the picture.

I've also been looking into running an Applet in the browser and communicating with a Servlet that then connects to the browser and then relays info from the database back to the Applet. I read this is the better way to do it to avoid connecting strait from the applet which is insecure and potentially allowing people access to the database. I'm not quite sure how they would go about injecting code and connecting to my database so if anyone could shed light on that topic I'd be grateful. Anyway I'm having trouble getting my Servlet to working. I'm using Tomcat and using the following code in my Applet:

```
private static URLConnection getServletConnection()
        throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
    URLConnection connection;

    // Open the servlet connection
    URL urlServlet = new URL("http://localhost:8080/examples/servlets/test_servlet");
    connection = urlServlet.openConnection();

    // Config
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.setDoOutput(true);

    connection.setUseCaches (false);
    connection.setDefaultUseCaches (false);

    connection.setRequestProperty(
            "Content-Type",
            "application/x-java-serialized-object");

    return connection;
}

private static void onSendData() {
    try {
        URLConnection connection;

        // get input data for sending
        String input = "Applet string heading for servlet";

        // send data to the servlet
        connection = getServletConnection();
        OutputStream outstream = connection.getOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(outstream);
        oos.writeObject(input);
        oos.flush();
        oos.close();

        // receive result from servlet
        InputStream instr = connection.getInputStream();
        ObjectInputStream inputFromServlet = new ObjectInputStream(instr);
        String result = (String) inputFromServlet.readObject();
        inputFromServlet.close();
        instr.close();

        // show result
        //textField.setText(result);
        System.out.println(result);

    } catch (java.net.MalformedURLException mue) {
        //textField.setText("Invalid serlvetUrl, error: " + mue.getMessage());
        System.out.println("Invalid serlvetUrl, error: " + mue.getMessage());
    } catch (java.io.IOException ioe) {
        //textField.setText("Couldn't open a URLConnection, error: " + ioe.getMessage());
        System.out.println("Couldn't open a URLConnection, error: " + ioe.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //textField.setText("Exception caught, error: " + e.getMessage());
        System.out.println("Exception caught, error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

My Servlet has the following code in it:

```
public class test_servlet extends HttpServlet {

protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
response.setContentType("text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1");
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
String defect = request.getParameter("defect").toString();

try {
    out.println("<html>");
    out.println("<head>");
    out.println("<title>Servlet</title>");
    out.println("</head>");
    out.println("<body>");
    out.println("<h1>Servlet at " + request.getContextPath() + "</h1>");
    out.println("<p>Defect: " + defect + "</p>");
    out.println("</body>");
    out.println("</html>");
} finally {
    out.close();
}
}

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
processRequest(request, response);
}

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {

try {
    response.setContentType("application/x-java-serialized-object");

    InputStream in = request.getInputStream();
    ObjectInputStream inputFromApplet = new ObjectInputStream(in);

    String servletText = "Text from Servlet";

    // echo it to the applet
    OutputStream outstr = response.getOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(outstr);
    oos.writeObject(servletText);
    oos.flush();
    oos.close();

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

processRequest(request, response);
}
```

It is giving me the "Couldn't open a URLConnection, error: http://localhost:8080/examples/servlets/test_servlet" response when I try to compile the Applet in Eclipse. I assume it probably has something to do with how/where I saved my Servlet file. I just threw it in the examples/servlet folder. This is all very confusing for me and I'm trying to figure out this Applet<->Servlet communication and how exactly to get it working. I've looked at other posts and they have gotten me this far.

Comment: *"This is all very confusing for me"*  Mixing applets, servlets and DBs in that situation will bring you lots of woes.  I'd suggest as step 1 to figure how to connect the servlet to the DB.  Only when that is working consider throwing an applet or JS into the mix.  (BTW - if an applet can connect to the servlet, so can JS.)

Comment: @AndrewThompson Hmm so I could go ahead with with Javascript/Canvas thing and communicate between JS and servlet and allow the servlet to do the communicating with the DB and respond back to the JS with the needed info?

Comment: I would not recommend doing *anything* until you have the servlet working.

Answer (score 1):

```
URL urlServlet = new URL("http://localhost:8080/examples/servlets/test_servlet");
connection = urlServlet.openConnection();
```

Don't form the URL like that.  Instead use something like..

```
URL urlServlet = new URL(getDocumentBase(), "../servlets/test_servlet");
connection = urlServlet.openConnection();
```

That presumes the applet is in a directory that is in the same directory as the `examples` directory.

Comment: That `../` part is not necessary by the way.